# SQL Server declare and execute query for temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (a BIGINT)
```

I want to do this

```
SELECT * FROM @t
```

but I need to do it by EXEC query, and this doesn't work

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT * FROM @t'
EXEC(@query)
```

how can I create a custom query to select the temp table?

Thanks.

Comment: You can replace temp table with hash table i.e (#t)

Comment: hi, i tried to apply hashTable, it looks worked. but then I need to drop the table everytime after the trigger is finished (the query ran within a trigger), is it correct? thanks

Comment: yes, you have to do that because it will create in memory

Comment: ok thanks., then i  will keep implementing in this aspect first. they looks more readable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hash table as below:

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table
(
    Name VARCHAR(50) 
)

insert into @tblTest values('Sandip')
insert into @tblTest values('AAA')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tblTest

SELECT * INTO #tblTest FROM @tblTest
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'SELECT * FROM #tblTest'

EXEC (@query)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: i found that i don't need to create #tblTest at all, where can i find the detail information about using #hashTable? can you tell me where I can find more information of it about how it is stored and how it actually work. Thanks.

Comment: search for : sql server hash table vs table variable

Answer (score 2):

This is because `EXEC` statement will execute the Statements in new Session. And the Table variables scope is fixed to the  batch of statement.

Since you declared the Table Variable out side of the Session , you can't access the table variable in EXEC statement.

So you need to DECLARE ,INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT table variables in the Dynamic Code itself.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT @query ='
DECLARE @t TABLE
        (
            a BIGINT
        )'

SELECT  @query += 'SELECT * FROM @t'
EXEC(@query)
```

**Solution 2:**

The another Solution is to create Global Temporary Table which we can create using `##`. And Global Temporary tables scope is limited to Database all connections.

```
CREATE TABLE ##TABLE1
    (
        a BIGINT
    )
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
SELECT  @query += 'SELECT * FROM ##TABLE1'
EXEC(@query)
```

But be aware if another user execute the same Query, there might be conflict with the same name creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE MyTable AS TABLE 
( 
 a BIGINT
);
GO


DECLARE @T AS MyTable;

EXEC sp_executesql
  N'SELECT * FROM @T',
  N'@T MyTable READONLY',
  @T=@T
```

please try this

Comment: It will create MyTable in database, which not required

Comment: it will not create table,It will make a table type.

Comment: @SandipPatel : please read answer carefully and than vote it down.

Comment: then can you please try to execute same statement in other window and see exception, obvious it create table as you have used create statement not declarative one

Comment: I don't want theory logic, just run your code in other window it need to be work there without any error

Comment: for other window you have to check for already existence if exist than no need to create the type.

Comment: It means table created dear

Comment: It is not table, It is table type

Comment: ha ha, It not mean that, you kill a person and tell me kill smarter then me, we are hear to help by best way. that's why i told not good otherwise idea is good

Comment: I have just provide solution to him/her which he/she wants. But it depends he/she is reliable with this solution or not.

Comment: and i give opinion on that, why you so much fustrate

Comment: No, I am not,By the way nice to talk you.